# codeigniter loses session due to redirect, is there a way to regenerate it?

Tags: session, codeigniter-2, sessionid

I've got a form that has, among other things, a preview button and a submit button. Let's say that the form contains a person's data. Clicking preview will submit the form to **example.com/preview** and get it opened in a new tab. The preview controller will insert the person's data in a table and, based on the value of LAST_INSERT_ID(), it will redirect to **example.com/person/ID**. When the redirect occurs, all session data is lost. I want to be able to keep session data so that, upon checking the **example.com/person/ID** page, the admin user can close it and do some changes to the form or submit it.

I've noticed that storing the session id in a flashdata item won't work, it won't get past the redirect. Also, if i somehow manage to get the session_id past the redirect (although adding it to the url is not what my client wants), I still don't know a way to regenerate the Codeigniter session with it. Another option I've looked into is using Codeigniter Native Session class, but the version I've found on the site is not for Codeigniter 2.0.0.3, and I'm afraid that using it might break something.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: firstly, you should not store your data upon previewing, secondly, you should explain better where is a problem and what code are you using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change my ci_sessions database table fields' collations to utf8_general_ci (the default was latin1_swedish_ci)